# sharepoint document file url to filestream

Tags: development

i want to retrieve the files from sharepoint document libraries url to filestream using aspx and c# coding.

Can any help me how to do it......?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this method to get a File object from a URL:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms476063.aspx

Use this method to read the data to a stream:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.openbinarystream.aspx

If you want to go through all files in a document library, you'll need to write a method that opens an SPList instance of your library, then gets a collection of listitems (SPListItemCollection) from that list, and access the SPListItem.File object of each item.

Comment: I used SPFile to downlaod the file. Its downloaded. When i tried to open, it is saying that "File is Corrupted"....? Can you have an idea 
Why it is happening..?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this old question, but maybe this will help someone:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile spFile = Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.Current.Web.GetFile( "subcat/test.docx" );
```

This will get the local file automatically for you, doing most of the work.

Comment: While this post may answer the question, we prefer more details such as "why". Please edit your post with additional details. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.